# Как центрировать блок по вертикали не зная его высоту?

Tags: css, css3

Я пока только один метод знаю:

```
.block {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Но когда я использую анимацию с трансформацией то позиция сбивается.

Comment: margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Попробуйте так: vertical-align: middle;

Comment: @ШерзодЁров а вы вопрос вообще читали? ВеРтИкАлЬнО

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `line-height` на всю высоту родительского блока. Или взгляните - https://habrahabr.ru/post/73113/

Comment: попробуйте `display: flex;` `align-items: center;`

Comment: А вы в анимации translateY(-50%) указываете?

Comment: Есть еще вариант через `display:table-cell;` и `vertical-align:middle;`

Answer (score 2):

`margin: auto` внутри `display: flex` отцентрирует по всем осям.

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.article {
  margin: auto;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ebf1f6 0%,#abd3ee 50%,#89c3eb 51%,#d5ebfb 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ebf1f6 0%,#abd3ee 50%,#89c3eb 51%,#d5ebfb 100%);
}
```

```html
<section class=block>
  <article class=article></article>
</section>
```